# Detect and read incoming SMS automatically in Delphi using TComPort

Tags: delphi, sms, tcomport

Am currently developing an app that receives SMS (using a GSM modem) and take actions depending on that SMS.

For example i will send SMS that contains "ClYellow", the software will detect automatically that incoming SMS, read it and take action, the action will be changing the background color to "ClYellow".

How can i do that using the TComPort ?

Comment: At first learn how to read received data (in OnRxChar event handler)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Have a look at [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: thanx @MBo, am familiar with such a thing, what next ?

Comment: Is your question "How do I change the background color?"

Comment: @LURD my question is clear, it's about receiving SMS and reading it, how can i make my app detects automatically new incoming SMSes (when a new SMS received a notification pop up - that's an extra) and read the content of that SMS, reading that SMS i mean placing the content of it in a variable then use that content in other instructions - for example the variable will the contain "Clyellow" ( which is the content of the SMS ), and i will do form1.color := the variable - this is just an example, waiting for yout help.

Comment: You just said that you were familiar with the `OnRxChar` event handler. Use that. For details, study examples on how to use `TComPort` and the modem manual.

Comment: @LURD I am, i have no problem with sending commands and reading responses using commands like "AT" or USSD commands in general, but SMS is new for me, i don't know what's the trick to make make my app intelligent enough to know that a new SMS is received and how to access the content of that SMS. I searched a lot but can't find what i need.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on the model of the phone you use. Let's assume that you successfully connected the phone to your COM port ans set up the port properly (the BAUD Rate, etc depend on the hardware you use, so nobody can give you better advice than the spec of the phone). The rule of thumb is that if you send the string `AT` to the device and it answers `OK`, you have successfully established a connection.

Now the next problem is to identify the list of AT commands that your phone supports. Unfortunately there were multiple standards and numerous extensions and exceptions from the standard. Try the `AT+CMGL="ALL"` command first.

Even more difficult to set up the connection to notify you of the new messages. This is a separate topic and even more depend on the phone model.

Hope that helps you to start googling the details.

Comment: thankx @dmitry-kuzminov but i think you didn't get my question, i already did all what you mentioned, the command  AT+CMGL="ALL" is to get the SMSes already received on the phone - i said am using a GSM modem plugged in a USB port.  The separate topic you talked about is what am searching for, i wish you can help.

Comment: @JeSSica I would advise you to reword the question because it has a lot of unnecessary details. If you know how to set up the COM port in Delphi, if you have successfully read the messages, and the meaningful part of your question is just how to receive the notification, than don't abuse the question with those details. As for the notifications, have you tried the `AT+CNMI`?

Comment: i know how to read messages already received but not new ones, i want to read the message just when its received, no i didn't try AT+CNMI, how can i use it ?